# How can i test my program with jvm type -server

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

I want to test performance of my code on both jvm types `-client` and `-server`
How can i switch among both jvm types in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you would run your application with any command-line switches (such as `-Xmx256m`). Just add it to the *Command Line Options* to the *Run Configuration* (you could create 2 configurations, one for each setting).

To be more specific:

1. Go to your application's *main* class
2. Run it
3. This should create a *Run* (or *Launch*) *Configuration*
4. Edit this configuration
5. Add `-client` or `-server` in the command-line switches

More information is available in the [**Eclipse Help**](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-java-local-configuration.htm)

Comment: Can you please be specific on how to do that, As i really don't no about setting jvm type.

Comment: -Xmx is for maximum heap memory I guess ? But what for jvm type?

Comment: Setting JVM type is as simple as putting `-client` in the command-line switches!